# Scala Spark PairRDD map unable to infer types

Tags: scala, apache-spark, lambda

I'm trying to call `map` on a PairRDD. Spark gives me this signature for it:

```
map[U](f: (A,B) => U)
```

I was expecting to fulfill that signature with:

```
pairRDD.map((k,v) => k) // minimalist example, I actually want something else
```

This gives me a type mismatch error, where Scala infers all types to be "Nothing". I don't understand why this happens. When I've seen a similar signatures for other functions, such as `aggregate`, I've been able to use this syntax. Why is this syntax not working in this case?

Comment: Actually, the function signature is `((A, B)) => U`. _i.e._ It is still a function of one argument, only that in this case the argument is a tuple. You can either write `pairRDD.map(tuple => tuple.1)` or even better, using pattern matching  `pairRDD.map { case (k,v) => k }`.

Comment: The signature that IntelliJ IDEA is showing me has `(A,B) => U` rather than `((A,B)) => U`.

Comment: I got it working with the other syntax you provided. Thanks! Although I still don't understand why I'm not fulfilling the signature with the syntax in OP.

Comment: IDEA, as any IDE, is not an actual compiler, and may be wrong. Lets see the process. In reality there is not `pairRDD`, only `RDD`. What we know as `pairRDD` is just a [ _(implicit)_ **wrapper** over an `RDD` of tuples](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) which provides helper functions that make sense for this kind of `RDDs` _(like `mapValues`)_. As you can see on the **scaladoc**, there is no `map` method on this wrapper, thus it is calling the one from a regular RDD which accepts a function of one argument, in this case a tuple.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated! (I will delete this comment soon)